# Call jquery plugin in directive only after data is renderer in DOM

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to initialize a jquery plugin in an angular directive but only after the service data is returned and first renderer in the DOM. 
I can seem to figure out how to do this in angular directive.
I have this code so far, but it seems that i am calling the plugin after the service data arrived, but before it is renderer on the DOM...
Any hints?

```
myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$watch("data.length", function( newValue, oldValue ) {
            if ( newValue === oldValue ) {
                console.log( "Should return..." );
                return; 
            }
            $(element).elastislide();
        });
    }
};
```

});

=== EDIT ====
If i postpone the execution using the setTimeout function it works, is this the right way to do this?

```
    myApp.directive('myDirective', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$watch("data.length", function( newValue, oldValue ) {
            if ( newValue === oldValue ) {
                console.log( "Should return..." );
                return; 
            }
            postpone = $timeout(function() {
                  $('#carousel').elastislide();                 
            }, 100);

        });
    }
};
```

});

Comment: is your directive responsible for creating some needed DOM elements?  It would help to clarify if you included the html markup with your angular directive.  Even better, create a jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net.

Comment: the html is not included in the directive as you can see in the code above. In generic terms, i am trying to find a solution to process data on the directive only after the DOM as finished loading.

Comment: but you have to call the directive somewhere in your html... I think it would be helpful to create a jsbin.com

Comment: You really need to post a plunker or JSFiddle for a question like this. Where is `data.length` coming from?? You also forgot to pass `$timeout` as an argument of your controller function. It sounds like what you need it a callback function or a custom event to run after the rendering. Does it work if you set your timeout to 0?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the DOM to **render** first, use [$timeout](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24timeout).

If you only need the DOM to be updated (but not rendered yet), use [$evalAsync](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24evalAsync).  Try this one first, as it may prevent flicker.

Comment: I haven't found anything like `$evalAsync`. Is this part of cutting-edge new version of AngularJS? Or already buried?